# C parallel implementation of Gauss elimination with MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I'm very new to MPI and I was asked to write a C parallel implementation for Gauss elimination (without pivoting).
I gave it a try (I used a row-wise decomposition) but my code doesn't work.  I am hoping someone can give me some pointers here. I've been looking for what's wrong for few days already without success :(
Thank you in advance !

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int i,j,k;
    int map[500];
    float A[500][500],b[500],c[500],x[500],sum=0.0;
    double range=1.0;
    int n=3;
    int rank, nprocs;
    clock_t begin1, end1, begin2, end2;
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);   /* get current process id */
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs); /* get number of processes */

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if (rank==0)
    {
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        A[i][j]=range*(1.0-2.0*(double)rand()/RAND_MAX);
        b[i]=range*(1.0-2.0*(double)rand()/RAND_MAX);
        }
        printf("\n Matrix A (generated randomly):\n");
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<n; j++)
            printf("%9.6lf ",A[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n Vector b (generated randomly):\n");
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            printf("%9.6lf ",b[i]);
        printf("\n\n");
    }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    begin1 =clock();

    MPI_Bcast (A,n*n,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast (b,n,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);    

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        map[i]= i % nprocs;
    } 

    for(k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
        MPI_Bcast (&A[k][k],n-k,MPI_DOUBLE,map[k],MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast (&b[k],1,MPI_DOUBLE,map[k],MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        for(i= k+1; i<n; i++) 
        {
            if(map[i] == rank)
            {
                c[i]=A[i][k]/A[k][k];
            }
        }               
        for(i= k+1; i<n; i++) 
        {       
            if(map[i] == rank)
            {
                for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
                    A[i][j]=A[i][j]-( c[i]*A[k][j] );
                }
                b[i]=b[i]-( c[i]*b[k] );
            }
        }
    }
    end1 = clock();

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    begin2 =clock();

    if (rank==0)
    { 
    x[n-1]=b[n-1]/A[n-1][n-1];
    for(i=n-2;i>=0;i--)
    {
        sum=0;

        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            sum=sum+A[i][j]*x[j];
        }
        x[i]=(b[i]-sum)/A[i][i];
    }

    end2 = clock();
    }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (rank==0)
    { 
        printf("\nThe solution is:");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("\nx%d=%f\t",i,x[i]);

        }

        printf("\n\nLU decomposition time: %f", (double)(end1 - begin1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        printf("\nBack substitution time: %f\n", (double)(end2 - begin2) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    }

    return(0);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting:
mpirun has exited due to process rank 1 with PID XXXX on node XXXX exiting without calling "finalize". This may have caused other processes in the application to be terminated by signals sent by mpirun (as reported here).

Answer (score 3):

As noticed by High Performance Mark, add `MPI_Finalize()` **before** `return(0)`. This code will run without prompting any problem...But the result will still be uncorrect. In parallel, it will print `nan` as being the result, which is false.

The problem comes from `MPI_Bcast(A,n*n,MPI_DOUBLE,...)`. `A` is defined as `float A[500][500]`.

- You need to broadcast the pointer to the first element `&A[0][0]`, not the pointer to the pointer to the first element.
- If you send `n*n` elements (n=3), you will send `A[0][0],...,A[0][8]` and `A[1][1]` will be left uninitialized. This could cause wrong results, such as `nan`. For the shake of simplicity (laziness...), you may change for `500*500`.
- `MPI_DOUBLE` corresponds to double precision... Solution is either to change for `double A[500][500]` or `MPI_Bcast(&A[0][0],500*500,MPI_FLOAT,...)`. Do the same thing for `b`.

This deterministic use of `rand()` is really useful for debugging purpose...Do not forget to use `srand()` to seed your random generator !

EDIT : here is the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int i,j,k;
    int map[500];
    double A[500][500],b[500],c[500],x[500],sum=0.0;
    double range=1.0;
    int n=3;
    int rank, nprocs;
    clock_t begin1, end1, begin2, end2;
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);   /* get current process id */
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs); /* get number of processes */

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if (rank==0)
    {
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<n; j++)
                A[i][j]=range*(1.0-2.0*(double)rand()/RAND_MAX);
            b[i]=range*(1.0-2.0*(double)rand()/RAND_MAX);
        }
        printf("\n Matrix A (generated randomly):\n");
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<n; j++)
                printf("%9.6lf ",A[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n Vector b (generated randomly):\n");
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            printf("%9.6lf ",b[i]);
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    begin1 =clock();

    MPI_Bcast (&A[0][0],500*500,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast (b,n,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);    

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        map[i]= i % nprocs;
    } 

    for(k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
        MPI_Bcast (&A[k][k],n-k,MPI_DOUBLE,map[k],MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast (&b[k],1,MPI_DOUBLE,map[k],MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        for(i= k+1; i<n; i++) 
        {
            if(map[i] == rank)
            {
                c[i]=A[i][k]/A[k][k];
            }
        }               
        for(i= k+1; i<n; i++) 
        {       
            if(map[i] == rank)
            {
                for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
                    A[i][j]=A[i][j]-( c[i]*A[k][j] );
                }
                b[i]=b[i]-( c[i]*b[k] );
            }
        }
    }
    end1 = clock();

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    begin2 =clock();

    if (rank==0)
    { 
        x[n-1]=b[n-1]/A[n-1][n-1];
        for(i=n-2;i>=0;i--)
        {
            sum=0;

            for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
            {
                sum=sum+A[i][j]*x[j];
            }
            x[i]=(b[i]-sum)/A[i][i];
        }

        end2 = clock();
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (rank==0)
    { 
        printf("\nThe solution is:");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("\nx%d=%f\t",i,x[i]);

        }

        printf("\n\nLU decomposition time: %f", (double)(end1 - begin1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        printf("\nBack substitution time: %f\n", (double)(end2 - begin2) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return(0);


}
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much !!!!  
I made ​​the necessary changes (The other Broadcasts are also incorrect  
+ It turns out that the second broadcast is made before the first one is finished => I used MPI_Barrier)  
But the code still doesn't work  
And I'm getting the following error:  
*** An error occurred in MPI_Bcast  
*** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD  
*** MPI_ERR_ROOT: invalid root  
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (your MPI job will now abort)  
:(

Comment: I think `MPI_Bcast()` is a blocking operation and i am very surprised that there is a need for `MPI_Barrier()`. And the other `MPI_Bcast()` seemed correct. The error may be triggered by `map[i]` not being in the right range or being different on each process. You may add something like `printf("%d : i=%d map[i]= %d\n",rank,i,map[i]);` before `MPI_Bcast()` to see what is happening.

Comment: Yes you are right !  
No need for `Barrier` and the error comes from the fact that only the 0 rank process knows the "map" values (I modified the code).  
How can I thank you ? I'm very grateful :D

Comment: Dear @francis, I think there is a little confusion about "n" variable in this post. Or maybe just me :) However, how the following piece of code can be correct since the number of variables must equal the dimension of the squared matrix (e.g 500)?
_MPI_Bcast (b,n,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);_

Comment: @FranciscoCunha : Indeed, 500 is the size of the array while n is the size of the matrix stored in the array. While A is handled as a n*n=3*3 matrix, the item A[1][1] is at location 1*500+1. Hence, `MPI_Bcast (b,500,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD); `  would also work as it uses the size of the memory buffer, but using the size of the vector `n` is sufficient and correct. While it's an easy way to provide a small array of variable size `n`, the right way to go would be to use dynamic memory allocation so that the sizes of the memory buffers always perfectly match those of matrix and vector.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not much of a C programmer but it looks to me as if you have probably called `return` prematurely.  Specifically you have called it before `MPI_Finalize()`. Try swapping the order of the statements.  Or even dropping the `return` altogether.

Comment: Still getting the same error :(  
Thank you for your help anyway !